# How does slow fade in/out on reCAPTCHA deter bots?

Tags: animation, bots, captcha

The [answer](https://superuser.com/a/1337825/728074) to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1337801) says that reCAPTCHA fade in speed depends on how likely the systems thinks you are a human.

What mechanism makes this a useful deterrent for bots? It seems like the human is hugely bothered by the wait while the bot is not at all. It can either just build in a wait to be sure or detect when the fade has completed which is a much less sophisticated task than completing the captcha itself. This seems like a terrible way to deter bots as it deters humans more.

Is there some (technical) reason that I am missing on why this delay will keep bots from answering the captcha?

Comment: Bots are unaware or unable to detect the fade out and fade in while humans irritated by the behavior will essentially ignore it ultimately. As why the developers decided to add this behavior is anyone’s guess.  Probably only Google knows.

Comment: @Ramhound, I was wondering whether there was a technical reason why this stops bots. I guess I should have formulated my question to more clearly be about this technical question. I have edited the question to make it clear it is not opinion based. I would accept as an answer a full explanation why something as simple as a fade would be capable of stopping bots. (The bot after all must be capable of a much more complicated task in order to pass the captcha then just detecting when a fade has finished (or just being "dumb" and waiting a while to be sure it has finished).

Comment: I think your question should be - how does captcha deter bots.  I can not vote to reopen as it stands.

Answer (score 1):

You have to consider multiple factors:

### Anti-bot measures don't only try to prevent them completely, but also slow them down

A human doesn't really mind waiting e.g. 1-2 seconds for the next step. Doing one slow captcha won't stop them from registering on a site where they have/want to register most of the time anyways. Humans don't do thousands of registrations or form submissions per day.

Bots, especially ones that send spam, want to go through as many sites as quickly as possible. Going through slow process, which also indicates higher security, might push them onto other less secured website instead of trying to wait to possibly be blocked for another reason.

### Variable slow down can be used to verify automation

If fade in time is random, it could attempt to detect if a bot tries to click an image before it's fully loaded. And it is for reCAPTCHA - very suspicious (= low scoring in terms of IP, browser fingerprint, etc.) solving attempts can get quite long times while for non-suspicious machines it usually loads much quicker.

Of course a bot can just be coded to always wait long enough and not be suspicious at all, it's not too hard to implement, but then we go back to the 1st point.

### Summary

Overall I don't think it's a great prevention method, but it's reasonable enough to not annoy users too much and also make the "life" of bots and their coders harder.

Fighting bots is all about balancing between not scaring the most vulnerable (e.g. elderly) users away while being effective. I personally prefer such methods being attempted than making actual things to solve more difficult - everyone once wondered if e.g. partial squares with traffic lights have to be selected or not.